# ERROR! no module/action detected in task in git clone ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I can't figure out what's happening here. This is my very simple ansible playbook:

```
---
  - name: "Playing with Ansible and Git"
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    tasks:
        - name: "clone the repo"
        - become: yes
        - git:
            repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples.git
            dest: /opt/
            clone: yes
            update: yes
```

**This is my version of ansible-playbook**

```
ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
```

**Error**

```
ERROR! no module/action detected in task.

The error appears to be in 'local.yml': line 6, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    tasks:
        - name: "clone the repo"
          ^ here
```

I am running by `ansible-playbook local.yml`

I really can't figure out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. This is working fine. I just have to remove `-` in front of git.

```
---
  - name: "Playing with Ansible and Git"
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    tasks:
        - name: "clone the repo"
          git:
            repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples.git
            dest: /opt/
            clone: yes
            update: yes
```